# PowerShell If Else logic not ok

Tags: powershell

Now my syntax problems are fixed (please don't look at the underscores missing, it's a problem on the website here) I'm having difficulty to have the 'ManagedBy' fields filled in with the 'Display name' of the manager (group or user). For one reason or another my if/else logic is not solid, as it only returns blancs.

```
$When = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-21)).Date  
Get-ADGroup -SearchBase "OU=Groups,OU=BEL,OU=EU,DC=domain,DC=net" -Filter {whenCreated -ge
$When} -Properties * |  Select whenCreated, cn, displayName,
GroupScope, GroupCategory, description, info, @{    
Label='managedBy';
Expression={    
if(Get-ADObject $_.managedBy.ObjectClass -eq "User" ) { (Get-ADUser $_.Manager -Properties displayName).displayName}    
Else{
     (Get-ADGroup $_.managedBy -Properties cn).cn 
     } 
  } 
} | Export-Csv
 "New groups -21 days.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" -Encoding
 utf8; start "New groups -21 days.csv"
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: the underscores missing aren't a problem of SO. The problem is that you paste your code in a horrible manner...

Comment: I'm sorry CB, I used the 'Quotes' on top. Can you tell me what the better way is? I will fix it then.

Comment: I have fixed it for you. I have removed the `>` sign in front of each line of code.

Comment: I understand it now CB, I just have to put 4 whitespaces in front, got it! Thx again :)

Comment: no! please read here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, your initial *Get-ADGroup* works fine(on win2012) and it's if/else which needed adjusting.

```
$When = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-21)).Date 
Get-ADGroup -SearchBase "OU=Groups,OU=BEL,OU=EU,DC=domain,DC=net" -Filter {whenCreated -ge
$When} -Properties * |  Select whenCreated, cn, displayName,
GroupScope, GroupCategory, description, info, 
@{
    Label='managedBy';
    Expression={
        $m = Get-ADObject -Identity $_.managedBy -Properties displayName,cn
        if($m.ObjectClass -eq "user") {
            $m.displayName} 
        Else{
            $m.cn
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Raf! I've been struggling with this for a long time now and I'm really happy to get it finally to work with your help. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be the same issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22669155/is-this-a-bug-in-powershell/22669395#22669395) question:

Variable expansion doesn't work in a scriptblock filter.  Try switching to an expandable string filter

```
Get-ADGroup -SearchBase "OU=Groups,OU=BEL,OU=EU,DC=domain,DC=net" -Filter "whenCreated -ge '$When'" -Properties *
```

Comment: I don't really understand it.. Can you be a bit more clear please? I'm a new noob in PowerShell and scripting in general, I'm sorry for this.

Comment: It's kind of an idiosyncracy of the AD Get-* cmdlet filters. You can use a filter script block or a filter string.  Variables within a script block don't get expanded, but they do if you us a string filter in an expandable string.